# devise with existing model creates overlapping routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

It's the first time i try to add devise authenticability to an already existing model. 
I've reproduced the problem in a very essential example (tested on ruby 2.1.1, rails 4.1.5, devise 3.3.0).

```
$ rails new devise_sample1 --database=postgresql
```

then i've create the model:

```
$ rails g scaffold custom_user name surname date_of_birth:date
```

Bear in mind that my model is called 'custom_user'.

Then i've tuned db configuration and i've created and migrated the db.

Now let's add devise, adding to the Gemfile the line:

```
gem 'devise'
```

As a first step, devise requires installation:

```
$ rails g devise:install
```

That in turn requires to add to config/environments/development.rb the following line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

At this point i'm ready to push devise into my existing model:

```
rails generate devise custom_user
```

So far so good; migrate again and start the server and connect to

```
http://localhost:3000/customer_users
```

via browser; push the button 'new customer_user".

Not surprisingly, here is what i get, that is the result of my scaffold:

[image]

But now let's push the button "Create Custom user".

**Here** is **what we'll get**:

[image]

**Amazing**. From my custom_user form, i end up to the registration form of devise. That means that routes are well inter-mixed.

So let's have a look at them:

```
GET    /custom_users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
POST   /custom_users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
DELETE /custom_users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
POST   /custom_users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
... (other password routes)
GET    /custom_users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
POST   /custom_users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
GET    /custom_users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
GET    /custom_users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
PATCH  /custom_users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
PUT    /custom_users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
DELETE /custom_users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
GET    /custom_users(.:format)               custom_users#index
POST   /custom_users(.:format)               custom_users#create
GET    /custom_users/new(.:format)           custom_users#new
GET    /custom_users/:id/edit(.:format)      custom_users#edit
GET    /custom_users/:id(.:format)           custom_users#show
PATCH  /custom_users/:id(.:format)           custom_users#update
PUT    /custom_users/:id(.:format)           custom_users#update
DELETE /custom_users/:id(.:format)           custom_users#destroy
```

So, the browser hits the "new" action then submits to the "create" action:

```
POST   /custom_users(.:format)               custom_users#create
```

that happens to be the very same route of:

```
POST   /custom_users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
```

The other routes seem not to overlap by chance rather than by design, so i've two questions.

1) **is this the way of integrating devise on an existing model** or have i lost some foundamental step?

2) if this is the way, **how am i supposed to fix it**?

Answer (score 1):

Your `custom_user` creation should happen through `devise registration` controller. To create/register new custom_user using devise use `new_custom_user_registration_path` (which will route you to `/custom_users/sign_up`) instead of `new_custom_user_path` (`/custom_users/new`). Even if you want to edit custom_user profile, use `edit_custom_user_registration_path` instead of `edit_custom_user_path`.

If you want to add other custom_user attributes to sign_up form you can customize the devise views. [See how to customize devise views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

Comment: in short are you saying that devise adopts your models but wants to use *his* views and not yours?

Comment: Not actually, I'm not sure what the use-case is for you. If you want to  create user from `user` class, and use `custom_users/new` allow `(params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)`. Add these fields to the form.

Comment: but in this case there is the clash on the submit that i've shown, so maybe things are like so: if i want to use my views i should remove 'registerable', while if i want to use the latter (and maybe customize it) then i have to remove my views. let say that they can both be used, but not at the same time, they don't mix very well

Answer (score 0):

You could use an other routename for devise. I add my own controller additionally

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise existingmodel

rake db:migrate

rails generate devise:controllers auth
```

in `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, class_name: :ExistingModel ,controllers: {
                   sessions: 'auth/sessions'
               }
```

it works in my environment...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
resources :custom_users
```

to another path:

```
resources :custom_users, path: 'custom_user'
```

This way, Devise will use `/custom_users`
while Scaffolded views will use `/custom_user`